# How to get last added id from table in djagno?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to get the last id for this i use

```
count_id = staff.objects.latest('id')
```

but the value it shows is (The total number of entries is 3)

```
staff object (3)
```

I wanted only 3

Comment: Put a `.id` on the end to get just the field you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for find last object You have 3 ways:**

1-

```
Staff.objects.last()  #if not change default sort
```

2-

```
Staff.objects.order_by("id").last() #always True
```

3-

```
Staff.objects.order_by("-id").first() #always True
```

**for give id from model have 2 main way**

**1- just select id from DB**

select id and return in dictionary template

```
Staff.objects.order_by("id").values("id").last() # output: {"id":3}
```

select id and return in list of tuples template

```
Staff.objects.order_by("id").values_list("id").last() # output: (86,)
```

select id and return in list template

```
Staff.objects.order_by("id").values_list("id", flat=True).last() # output: 86
```

**2- Select all field and view one**

```
Staff.objects.order_by("id").last().id
```